# XML PATH ELEMENTS XSINIL without replicate xmlns:xsi

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql, for-xml-path

I need to extract XML from table, with null value:

```
<RoomNo xsi:nil="true" />
```

So I use the clause **elements xsinil**:

```
for xml path('root'), elements xsinil
```

My problem is in the extraction of a complex XML made with subqueries. The clause **elements xsinil** insert in every subquery the code **xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"**

If I remove the inner **elements xsinil** I lose the null fields.

With this query:

```
    -- Test table
    CREATE TABLE #TestTable (StudentName VARCHAR(100), Course VARCHAR(100), Instructor VARCHAR(100), RoomNo VARCHAR(100))
    GO
    INSERT INTO #TestTable (StudentName, Course, Instructor, RoomNo)
    SELECT 'Mark', 'Algebra', 'Dr. James', '101'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Mark', 'Maths', 'Dr. Jones', '201'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joe', 'Algebra', 'Dr. James', null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joe', 'Science', 'Dr. Ross', '301'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Joe', 'Geography', 'Dr. Lisa', null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jenny', 'Algebra', 'Dr. James', '101'
    GO


    -- Xpath query
    select -- node STUDENT
        A.StudentName,
        (
            select -- node TEST
            Instructor as '@Instructor', Course as 'Course', RoomNo as 'RoomNo'
            from #TestTable B where B.StudentName = A.StudentName
            for xml path('test'), type, elements xsinil
            ) as 'node()'
    from (select distinct StudentName from #TestTable) A
    for xml path('student'), root('root'), type, elements xsinil

    -- end
    drop TABLE #TestTable
```

I got:

```
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <student>
        <StudentName>Jenny</StudentName>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo>101</RoomNo>
        </test>
      </student>
      <student>
        <StudentName>Joe</StudentName>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo xsi:nil="true" />
        </test>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. Ross">
          <Course>Science</Course>
          <RoomNo>301</RoomNo>
        </test>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. Lisa">
          <Course>Geography</Course>
          <RoomNo xsi:nil="true" />
        </test>
      </student>
      <student>
        <StudentName>Mark</StudentName>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo>101</RoomNo>
        </test>
        <test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Instructor="Dr. Jones">
          <Course>Maths</Course>
          <RoomNo>201</RoomNo>
        </test>
      </student>
    </root>
```

But I need:

```
    <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <student>
        <StudentName>Jenny</StudentName>
        <test Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo>101</RoomNo>
        </test>
      </student>
      <student>
        <StudentName>Joe</StudentName>
        <test Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo xsi:nil="true" />
        </test>
        <test Instructor="Dr. Ross">
          <Course>Science</Course>
          <RoomNo>301</RoomNo>
        </test>
        <test Instructor="Dr. Lisa">
          <Course>Geography</Course>
          <RoomNo xsi:nil="true" />
        </test>
      </student>
      <student>
        <StudentName>Mark</StudentName>
        <test Instructor="Dr. James">
          <Course>Algebra</Course>
          <RoomNo>101</RoomNo>
        </test>
        <test Instructor="Dr. Jones">
          <Course>Maths</Course>
          <RoomNo>201</RoomNo>
        </test>
      </student>
    </root>
```

Comment: If you "need" the second form, that's an indication that something's working with XML as *strings* rather than using one of the many libraries or tools that actually works with XML *as* XML. From an *information* perspective, both documents are the same.

Comment: Thanks. I need to send XML to some Webservices that aren't ... perfect, and I try to add anything that the WS may not be expecting. Unfortunately, I won't be able to do tests for days.

Comment: [How to remove xmlns from child elements with FOR XML](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23624/how-to-remove-xmlns-from-child-elements-with-for-xml/23697#23697)